# OnClickListener doesnt "listen"

Tags: android, for-loop, onclicklistener

I'm trying to listen to increasingly number of clicks, but the "OnClickListeners" method won't even listen to one of them, if I put it in a "for" loop. Here's the code:

```
show_seq(0);
    while (!check) {

                          // k = 0 at first 

        for (int listen = 0; listen <= k; listen++) { 
            OnClickListeners();
        }
        checkWin();
    }
```

and the "OnClickListeners" method:

```
private void OnClickListeners() {
    bird.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getButton(1);
        }
    }); ...
```

any ideas?

Comment: yes and it actually goes into the method, i checked it in the Debugger

Comment: How does `getButton()` look like?

Answer (score 1):

if You try to listen to num of clicks done on one Button ..

```
    bird.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sum++;System.out.printLn(sum);
    }
});
```

put int sum=0;

may be i don`t understand your question right :( ..

Answer (score 0):

Setting the OnCLickListener more than once will not make a difference, you should ideally set this up outside of any loop (e.g. in onCreate).

It looks like you might be approaching this in the wrong way, what is the while loop doing? You should try and implement event listeners in such a way that they are reactive and that the event will trigger any other additional code you need to happen. If you're looking to catch multiple clicks of a view then you should easily be able to achieve this within the listener code.

Comment: i want to do the "simon says" game. It first there is one click, then two and so on...

Comment: Set an integer counter and increment it when the view is clicked? If you need to check the time between the events this should be fairly simple too, something like:
int lastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Then compare with the time of the previous click.

Comment: what i want is to show a increasingly sequence of buttons being shown/hidden and then await for clicks after each sequence (also in a increasingly number)

Comment: i want to implement the game "simon Says". You know it?